# Retrieving sending statistics applicable to Amazon SES service

Tags: java, amazon-s3, amazon-sns, amazon-ses, amazon-cloudwatch

I am writing Java app which sends email via Amazon SES service, and that works fine. But now I need to retrieve email sending statistics as granural as per email ID basis.

So, I use **CloudWatch** and pass the notifications to **SNS**. Yet, I cannot infer away how to get the statistics as per explicit request to the Web service. The SNS endpoints are able to dispatch the data as on needing basis. **When I want to make explicit request from my app on service for stats.**

The **S3 service** is for storage. Do I need to store stats somehow on it, so that later I can query it?
Any resolutions and details are appretiated?

Comment: For some reasons, I need to stick to Amazon services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is the way I got the sending stats.
When it comes to **Amazon SES**, it gives you very limited sending statistics; not pointing to particular sent email.

Then when it comes to **Amazon Cloudwatch**, it gives you very similar statistics as the SES, is that it gives you a chance to make the stats dates appear precise to the extend of minutes. Meaning that if you know when you sent the email, via SES, by storing it on DB, you can estimate which stat belongs to which email.

Then you can use the **Amazon Firehose** combined with **Amazon S3**. This is where I landed. The Firehose is a stream which pushes statistics on the S3 storage. The SES provides the *configuration set* which lets you attach it.
The S3 stores anything you like, including email sending statistics. You can have up to 5 stats:

- Send
- Delivered
- Bounce
- Complaint
- Reject

The stats are stored in files which you can access and read by using **Amazon's SDK** pertaining to **Java language**.[The way to query in Java](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RetrievingObjectUsingJava.html)

What you get then is **JSON** file of email sending statistics, e.g.,

```
    {
   "eventType":"Bounce",
   "bounce":{
      "bounceType":"Permanent",
      "bounceSubType":"General",
      "bouncedRecipients":[
         {
            "emailAddress":"recipient@example.com",
            "action":"failed",
            "status":"5.1.1",
            "diagnosticCode":"smtp; 550 5.1.1 user unknown"
         }
      ],
      "timestamp":"2016-10-14T05:02:52.574Z",
      "feedbackId":"EXAMPLE7c1923f27-ab0c24cb-5d9f-4e77-99b8-85e4cb3a33bb-000000",
      "reportingMTA":"dsn; ses-example.com"
   },
   "mail":{
      "timestamp":"2016-10-14T05:02:16.645Z",
      "source":"sender@example.com",
      "sourceArn":"arn:aws:ses:us-east-1:123456789012:identity/sender@example.com",
      "sendingAccountId":"123456789012",
      "messageId":"EXAMPLE7c191be45-e9aedb9a-02f9-4d12-a87d-dd0099a07f8a-000000",
      "destination":[
         "recipient@example.com"
      ],
      "headersTruncated":false,
      "headers":[
         {
            "name":"From",
            "value":"sender@example.com"
         },
         {
            "name":"To",
            "value":"recipient@example.com"
         },
         {
            "name":"Subject",
            "value":"Email Subject"
         },
         {
            "name":"MIME-Version",
            "value":"1.0"
         },
         {
            "name":"Content-Type",
            "value":"multipart/mixed;  boundary=\"----=_Part_0_716996660.1476421336341\""
         },
         {
            "name":"X-SES-MESSAGE-TAGS",
            "value":"myCustomTag1=myCustomTagValue1, myCustomTag2=myCustomTagValue2"
         }
      ],
      "commonHeaders":{
         "from":[
            "sender@example.com"
         ],
         "to":[
            "recipient@example.com"
         ],
         "messageId":"EXAMPLE7c191be45-e9aedb9a-02f9-4d12-a87d-dd0099a07f8a-000000",
         "subject":"Email Subject"
      },
      "tags":{
         "ses:configuration-set":[
            "my-configuration-set"
         ],
         "ses:source-ip":[
            "192.0.2.0"
         ],
         "ses:from-domain":[
            "example.com"
         ],
         "ses:caller-identity":[
            "ses_user"
         ],
         "myCustomTag1":[
            "myCustomTagValue1"
         ],
         "myCustomTag2":[
            "myCustomTagValue2"
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

That is about it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi For your requirement as per my understanding AWS Dynamo DB is the best way. AWS Dynamo DB is a No sql related DB. After sending email you can store the result (emailId, if you want time ect..) into Dynamo DB by using SNS, or nay lambda functions. You can fire a query to dynamo DB to get the statistics.

If you want to go with S3 bucket way, you have a maintain one json file, and each time need to overwrite that file.

Comment: Let us focus on SQL like DB, cause I don't know NoSQL. Can you provide more details on how to do what I want to do with the S3 sevice.

Comment: First create a sample json file and keep that in s3 bucket. Write a lambda function that should be a listener to SNS message. Once your email sending is success then publish one SNS message, then automatically your lambda function will gets executes. Now your lambda function will receive the email id details from SNS, so you have to read the existing json file from s3 bucket and add the new email there finally store the file in the same bucket with same name. When ever you want you can call JSON file to get analytic data.